# Delphi 10.4: How to start writing Android apps?

Tags: android, delphi, installation, ide, platform

Until now I have only programmed for Windows, but I would like to try Android.

So, I installed Delphi 10.4 CE with all the options.

Then, I installed all the recommended stuff with SDK Manager.

Then, I connected my (Huawei) phone to my (Windows 10) laptop with USB, and found out how to activate the developer mode and remote debugging.

Then, I created a blank multi device application.

But still, Delphi refuses to even show the "Android" option! (I can only select "Windows 32 bit")

What am I missing? I'm getting desperate after so many hours of searching!

There is no Android option in the Delphi IDE:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to right-click on the target platforms and select "Add Platform" to add Android as an option? Maybe Android isn't added as a platform option in your current project?

Comment: No, that's exactly the problem.  And Delphi says everything is installed...

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your issue is that Android hasn't been added as a platform option within your project.

First, you'll need to make sure that you have the Android platform installed. You can do this by going to "Tools" and then "Manage Platforms..." from the main menu:
[image]

Once you have the Android Platform installed in your IDE, then within your project, you can add it as a platform option by right-clicking on the "Target Platforms" option in your Projects window, then selecting "Add Platform...":

[image: Target Platforms - Add Platform]

Within that menu, you'll be able to select Android as an option as can be seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

Once you have Android added as a platform option, then you should see your phone under "Target":

[image]

If you're not sure where to find your Projects window, see below:

[image]

Comment: Well, that is exactly what isn't working...
I have installed everything, but still only one target is appearing (win32)!

Comment: @KoenVandeMoortel So you do not see Android under the Add Platform menu at all? What do you see there?

Comment: Only Windows32.  And I installed everything, also Mac & IOS...

Comment: Update: I reinstalled everything... no change!  Now, yesterday, 24h later, without touching anything, the options suddenly popped up in the Delphi IDE!  Very weird, like "something" was still installing "something" behind my back without telling me anything!  Very annoying and confusing!  But I finally got my first "Hello world!" on Android!